# Open a short video using QuickTime Player

Tags: swift5

I have a short video on my local machine. I am trying to open it using `NSWorkspace` on QuickTime Player.

```
let stringUrl = "~/Desktop/myrec.mov"
let url = URL(string: stringUrl)!

let config = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
config.activates = true

NSWorkspace.shared.open(
    [url],
    withApplicationAt: URL(string: "~/Applications/QuickTime Player")!,
    configuration: config
)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file cap/cap.swift
```

Which has to do with `withApplicationAt` being the incorrect URL and returning `nil`.

I'm sure `withApplicationAtURL` is wrong, but I have no idea how to find the url for the quicktime player app.

I am very new to Swift and am having trouble reading the docs, especially since they don't seem up to date (e.g. my compiler says `openFile` is deprecated and led me to `open`).

I'm also not sure if this is the correct/best way to go about accomplishing what I am trying to do (open a small local video on quicktime player).

Any recommendations, tips, advice, or answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `~/Applications/QuickTime Player.app`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what documentation you looked at, but this has a huge deprecation warning: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1528548-open

Comment: @idmean, I actually just tried that and now I'm getting this `Pure virtual function called!`, which probably has to do with `OpenConfiguration()`.

Comment: @idmean, the deprecation warning is interesting. As I mentioned, my compiler was telling me to use it.. Maybe the args are different? I'll try again. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: I changed it to `openURLs` and got this: `error: 'openURLs(_:withApplicationAtURL:configuration:completionHandler:)' has been renamed to 'open(_:withApplicationAt:configuration:completionHandler:)'`

Comment: My swift version is `Apple Swift version 5.3.2`

Comment: While I have not solved the entire problem, I now know that `url` is not an acceptable file url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Works on my Mac:

```
let stringUrl = "/Users/whoever/Desktop/myrec.mov"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: stringUrl)

let config = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
config.activates = true

NSWorkspace.shared.open(
    [url],
    withApplicationAt: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Applications/QuickTime Player.app"),
    configuration: config
)
```

Please note that that I replaced the initializer of URL with the correct one. Also note, that I've swapped the QuickTime Player path with the one that Finder gives me (right-click while holding option key).

Comment: Yeah I just realized my `url` was completely wrong. I could get the correct url by using `FileManager`. Thanks for the note regarding the correct URL initializer, I'll give this a try right now!

Comment: This worked to some extent — I didn't get a compiler error. But I'm still not seeing a video pop up :(

Comment: @Algebra8 Make sure you use absolute paths. Check the logs. Also, make sure your app is not sandboxed.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to check if my script is sandboxed. I'm just compiling using `swift` in terminal.

Comment: @Algebra8 But then I guess you didn't post all your code? Because you would need to import AppKit or Cocoa for this code to compile? Anyways, I doubt that you can do things like that with a plain Unix executable, which, btw, are never sandboxed. Create a Cocoa App with Xcode (that's what I did, too).

Comment: Ah, interesting. I did import AppKit, which is how I'm using NSWorkspace. Sorry I didn't show all my imports. I'll try creating a cocoa app with xcode, but the idea that swift code has some, or a lot of, dependency with xcode kind of irks me. Thanks for your troubles, I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: @Algebra8 Don't sweat it. I was just surprised you were invoking the compiler on the command-line. Swift and the open source parts of Foundation don't depend on Xcode at all. But you're trying to interact with macOS features of the kind that often require you to be a proper app with an Info.plist and AppDelegate. (Which you could, of course write by hand too...)

Comment: oooh, wow that explains a lot. Thanks a bunch, I really appreciate the extra info :)